# Dependency 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery:' not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

I am following the [spring cloud consul documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/docs/current/reference/html) on version 3.1.0 and I was trying to replicate the step by step documentation, in which it shows this set of dependencies to be applied, one of them is this spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery, but it always appears that it does not exist, what am I doing wrong, I forgot to configure something in pom?

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.wildrimak</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-consul-tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-consul-tests</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>3.1.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I hope I can configure the consul following the documentation

Comment: Your missing a spring-cloud.version property

Comment: Thanks a lot, @spencergibb  I made the suggested change in my question, but I still have the problem "Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:3.1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)".

Sorry if I forgot something, it's my first time using stackoverflow to ask questions, I think it's strange that I have this problem, because the dependency is suggested in the official spring-cloud-consul documentation, so I think I may have misunderstood the process of configuring it.

Comment: Spring cloud bom doesn't have a 3.x.y version, it's 2021.0.1. Look at start.spring.io